# Calculate Sum that cross 3 tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have 3 tables (trx_batch, trx_doc_trx_item).
I want user to enter id(trx_batch). Then the system will auto calculate the sum of trx_item which linked to trx_doc, and trx_doc is linked to trx_batch.

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trx_batch` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batchDate` date NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trx_doc` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idBatch` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trx_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDoc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(14,4) NOT NULL,
  `amtTax` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Sample data that I have:
    trx_batch
   id: 1

```
trx_doc
id:1
idBatch: 1

trx_item:
id:1
idDoc:1
amount: 500
amtTax : 30

id:2
idDoc:1
amount:100
amtTax:20
```

If user enter 1 as id for trx_batch. The total should be 650.00. 
How to write in mysql format? Please help me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    SUM( COALESCE( i.amount, 0 ) + COALESCE( i.amtTax, 0 ) ) AS SumAmountAndTax
FROM
    trx_item AS i
    INNER JOIN trx_doc   AS d ON i.idDoc   = doc.id
    INNER JOIN trx_batch AS b ON d.idBatch = b.id
WHERE
    b.id = :batchIdParameterValue
```

Comment: Common yar, why are you doing his home works? Let him make a try atleast

Comment: already tried that's why I am seeking for help.. @un-lucky why you judge me? How do you know that I never try?

Comment: Now I know which part went wrong.. thank you so much @Dai

Comment: @chonglt: With all respect, let me ask How do i know you have tried something without specifying in the post? You must read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before raising next question